# Use a real git repo during an Openshift build?

Tags: git, openshift

When Openshift builds from a git repository, the source is cloned/exported in such a way that the clone is not a git repo, i.e. there's no .git directory. Anyone know how to change this behaviour to a real clone?

There's nothing in the relevant documentation (https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#source-code) but the docs aren't always what they could be.

Our use case is that our project uses a gradle plugin that adds information about the git state to the build artefact. This won't build in Openshift.

Comment: Can you confirm which OpenShift S2I builder you are using? Although a ``.git`` directory may be created in some cases, S2I builders may deliberately ignore it and not move it to the ``src`` directory where builds are done. A fiddle may be needed to ensure it is preserved, but need to know what S2I builder you are using.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamDumpleton – it's a custom s2i written in-house. Now that I look at its code more closely I realise that it's to blame. The good news is I can fix it :-)  If you were to leave an answer along similar lines to your comment, I could accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When writing a S2I builder, by default source code will be injected into the directory `/tmp/src`. Your custom `assemble` script, if it needs to keep files from what is being injected, would move or copy files to their final location, such as `/opt/app-root/src`. Usually this is done before any compilation phase if it occurs. The build would then run in the target directory.

When moving or copying files and using a glob wildcard, you need to make sure hidden files starting with '.' are included. For example:

```
shopt -s dotglob
echo "---> Installing application source ..."
mv /tmp/src/* ./
```

If you don't have `shopt -s dotglob`, then a directory such as `.git` would not be included. This would be a problem if the subsequent build expected the `.git` directory to exist.

If you were using someone else's S2I builder and the `.git` directory was being left behind, you could include an executable `.s2i/bin/assemble` script in your application code directory and add to it.

```
#!/bin/bash

mv /tmp/src/.git ./

/usr/libexec/s2i/assemble
```

This assumes original `assemble` script was in typical location of `/usr/libexec/s2i/`.

Comment: Above and beyond!

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of going against the authoritative answer (literally) I found that I didn't need a custom assemble script. Indeed, the `.git` directory wasn't available in `/tmp/src` at all. It may have been that my situation is different as I was doing a copy such as:

```
s2i build file://$(pwd) --copy --keep-symlinks ${S2I_IMAGE} ${IMAGE_TO_BUILD}
```

In this situation there is a regexp which excludes the `.git` directory from being copied (found through an issue at https://github.com/openshift/source-to-image/issues/457). In my case therefore, I needed to not exclude that `.git` directory by setting the exclude regexp:

```
s2i build file://$(pwd) --exclude="" --copy --keep-symlinks ${S2I_IMAGE} ${IMAGE_TO_BUILD}
```

With this, there was no need to change the assemble script, the `.git` directory was being copied into the assemble context no problem at all.